# How can i have webdriver refresh but submit form data every refresh?

Tags: forms, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, captcha

So essentially driver.refresh() does not submit form data for example a captcha on the page. If you refresh in a browser, a pop-up appears saying confirm form resubmission if you click continue the browser submits the form data and you don't have to solve the captcha again. Is there any way that I can automate selenium to confirm the form resubmission every driver.refresh() ?

[image: confirm form resubmission]

Comment: please share the html code of page if Ryan solution mentioned below will not work

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is an alert, which is what it appears to be, you simply add this line of code after you call for the driver to refresh.

```
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

Yes, you could write a Custom driver class, which extends the selenium driver class you are using, and overwrite the refresh method(or make your own). But, that would be bad practice.

Since not all pages you automate against will have form data.